# Path where I store profile pictures is unreachable in production mode

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, multer

My goal is to upload a profile picture. I did this in development mode using multer in Node.js. Multer asks for a path where to save the new picture.

In development mode, my Angular frontend and my Node.js backend were in the same file (see below for the project structure). The destination path used in Multer worked for development mode.

I then deployed my backend and frontend separately and now this path doesn't work. How can I make sure that the uploaded profile pictures end up in the same map as it did in development?

This is the structure in development mode. SRC map contains the Angular frontend code and backend contains the Node.js backend.

[image]

This is the path I used to store uploaded profile pictures with Multer. The problem now is that I deployed my backend and frontend separately to Heroku and so this path doesn't work anymore.

[image]

How can I change my path so that my uploaded profile pictures still get added to this assets/images/profile-pictures map?

Comment: If you deployed them to separate instances, you can't. How come you want them in the assets folder?

Comment: Well, I don't know how else I could display them in my angular front end. What are my options?

Comment: Store them in a folder somewhere on that server, and use express or whatever web framework you're using to expose any images within that folder. You can then use that URL instead, i.e. from angular you will have `<img src="http://yourbackend.com/yourfolder/yourimage.png" />`

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not going to work on Heroku. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The filesystem that Heroku provides is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): any changes you make to it will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

Instead of storing uploaded files on the local filesystem, Heroku [recommends storing them on a third-party service like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3). The [`multer-s3` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3) should let you do that fairly easily.

Once the files have been stored you can access them via Amazon's SDK or, if you've configured your uploads accordingly, via HTTP. Regular HTTP access can be [authenticated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) or anonymous.